# Show last published result

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get last published result.Suppose My Current Date is 01-08-2019 and time is 11:00.Then i will get result of row no 2(ID) OR (another)Current Date is 02-08-2019 and 13:00 then I will get row no 5(ID).

**Note: Based on current date & Time**

```
id        date          time    number

1   |   31-07-2019  |  12:30  |   20
2   |   31-07-2019  |  18:30  |   35
3   |   01-08-2019  |  12:30  |   40
4   |   01-08-2019  |  18:30  |   70
5   |   02-08-2019  |  12:30  |   21
6   |   02-08-2019  |  18:30  |   61
```

Comment: you need a closet last published result based on given date? ot just latest?

Comment: Exactly.I want to get latest or closest records based on current date & time

Comment: Might i suggest you combine Columns Date and Time together?

Comment: Store dates using a date data type

Answer (score 1):

It just a SQL query for example:

```
SELECT * FROM `ENTER_HERE_YOUR_TABLE_NAME` ORDER BY `date`, `time` DESC LIMIT 1
```

No extras needed.

Should be work fine in your case.

Comment: Thought I should also add, the query you suggested would still produce a wrong result. for your future reference, In the `Order By` clause you must specify the type of order, otherwise default it would assume `Asc`.

Comment: I know but in case of your awnser I wrote in to my awnser following line:
```SELECT * FROM `ENTER_HERE_YOUR_TABLE_NAME` ORDER BY `date`, `time` DESC LIMIT 1 ``` so maybe there was a copy past error or something else xD my Query should be fine xD

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a comparison with the current Server's Time use `NoW()` otherwise you can input your own time for example '2018-12-31 18:30'

```
SELECT * FROM `YourTable` 
where `Date` <= Now() AND `Time` <= DATE_FORMAT(Now(), '%H:%i') 
Order by `Date` Desc,`Time` Desc LIMIT 1;
```

Also Looking at your current `Date` Column you may be using the wrong datatype... you may consider creating the table to something like this (Where i used the datatype `Date`)

```
CREATE TABLE `YourTable` (
  `ID` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `Time` TIME NOT NULL,
  `Number` INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);
```

Or even better you could combine both `Date` and `time` together

```
CREATE TABLE `YourTable` (
  `ID` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `Number` INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);
```

With the above structre, you could simplify your query to

```
SELECT * FROM `YourTable` 
where `Date` <= Now() 
Order by `Date` Desc LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id from tablename where date<='01-08-2019' and time<='11:00' order by date,time desc limit 1
```

Comment: While it answers the question, it is better include some additional information alongside the code. Like `You can order the results by time and select the first one using the limit clause https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html`. And format the code onto multiple lines. Answers with links and proper code formatting are usually more helpful and more likely to get upvotes and etc, while code-only answers automatically end up in LQP queue - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345719/low-quality-posts-and-code-only-answers

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you have difficulties in changing your current table datatype.

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable 
WHERE date = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%d-%m-%Y') 
AND time <= TIME_FORMAT(CURTIME(),'%H:%i')
ORDER BY time DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```